# Use custom font in AWS Cognito Hosted UI

Tags: html, web, amazon-cognito

We are using Hosted UI in AWS Cognito for logins. As an option available, we changed styling of the font and other css part but we also want to use our own/premium font (not the web safe fonts). Is there any way we can achieve this?

We do know that we have option to host our own UI but it is kind of last resort. Any workaround for this within Hosted UI?

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible as of February 2024.